# zsim. pin error :$PINPATH environment variable with Pin's path

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, scons, intel-pin

I want to compile zsim (https://github.com/s5z/zsim)

```
~/zsim$ scons -j16
```

then there is an error message

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Building opt zsim at build/opt
ERROR: You need to define the $PINPATH environment variable with Pin's path
```

but when i just common pin

```
$ pin
E: Missing application name
Pin 3.2
Copyright (c) 2003-2016, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
VERSION: 81201 DATE: Feb  2 2017
Usage: pin [OPTION] [-t <tool> [<toolargs>]] -- <command line>
Use -help for a description of options
```

it can find pin, how can fix it,thanks

os:ubuntu 12.04
gcc:4.6.3
g++:4.6.3
pin:3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the readme specifies the following:
(https://github.com/s5z/zsim/blob/master/README.md)

> Download Pin, http://www.pintool.org . Tested with Pin 2.8+ on an
>   x86-64 architecture. Compiler flags are set up for Pin 2.9 on x86-64.
>   To get flags for other versions, examine the Pin makefile or derive
>   from sample pintools. Set the PINPATH environment variable to Pin's
>   base directory.

Sounds like you need to do the following

```
export PINPATH=<Base directory of your pin install>
```

Comment: It's work! But appear another error 
scons: *** [build/opt/access_tracing.ot] Error 1
scons: *** [build/opt/access_tracing.os] Error 1
scons: *** [build/opt/decoder.os] Error 1
scons: *** [build/opt/detailed_mem.os] Error 1
scons: *** [build/opt/contention_sim.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.